# Why the network request of web3 interaction through react or any other frontend framework or library is not showing in the network tab of browser?

Tags: web3js, react, network, external-api, rpc

All network request we make from browser is shows in the network tab , but the web3 request is not showing in the web browser. Web3 library uses network RPC to interact with the blockchain. The RPC is one type of network api but why it is not showing any request in the network tab of browser ? Is web3 Library is using any method to hide these requests or using any other methods if you know any kind of information related to this plz let me know.

Comment: It is likely it uses a different channel, like websockets.

Comment: But if we use wss then it will also display the request in the network tab

Comment: Are you using metamask? or similar wallet,

Comment: yes, i'm using metamask. but i'm also requesting data from my react app